# Migrating to Struts 2.5.16 causing log4 issue

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, log4j2

I'm migrating existing Struts Application 2.3.34 to 2.5.16. 
I've updated my Project with all the libs from min distribution needed for the upgrade. 
At Server (Tomcat 8.5) startup I see ERROR in the console:
***ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...***
Looks like they are missing log4j-core lib in it?
Please let me know if anyone experienced similar issue or if I'm missing anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Who is "they"? What's your pom look like? Without any details it's really difficult to help.

Comment: Hi Dave, We don't use Maven. I meant the downloaded min lib package for version 2.5.16 is missing the above mentioned jar file - http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/struts/2.5.16/struts-2.5.16-min-lib.zip

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of struts 2 (V2.5.16) uses log4j2 jar. You can refer [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration) for more details. If you already have log4j2 in your webapp, try updating it to the [latest version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.10.0).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. As struts 2.5.16 uses log4j2, we have to add that to our class path. Once we add this to our project I am not getting the struts logs as we have log4j.xml file.

So I started migrating application logs and hibernate logs but at some point its not working..

The simple work around is instead of migrating the complete project to log4j2
use the log4j-to-slf4j adapter jar, which will make your struts module to work with the existing slf4j implementation. I did these pom changes:

```
<dependency>
        <!--Defining not to use the log4j-api -->
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>${struts.ver}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>org.apache.commons</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-lang3</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> <!-- Redirecting from log4j2 to slf4j -->
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Refer to the "log4j-to-slf4j adapter jar" in [this page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html)